# iggrid append on rows feature issue with igHierarchicalGrid

Tags: iggrid

i am using append on rows feature on igHierarchicalGrid.
everything loads correctly but when i expand any row and then click load more button then it sends page=1 instead of correct page like 3(if we are going to click 3rd time on load more button) due to this server sends data according to page.

have anyone encountered this issue?
any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

igGrid's `AppendRowsOnDemand` feature is not supported in igHierarchicalGrid.